# How do you differentiate $x^{\cos(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

How do you differentiate $x^{\cos(x)}$

I encounter this problem in my homework but I don't know how to differentiate it. Do you need use logarithmic differentiation to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why is this topic on hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$y=x^{\cos(x)}$$ then we get by taking the logarithm
$$\ln(y)=\cos(x)\ln(x)$$ and now by the chain rule we obtain:
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=-\sin(x)\ln(x)+\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Why $ln(y)=\cos(x)\ln(x)$?

Comment: Since we have $$\ln(x^r)=r\ln(x)$$

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, is your problem solved now?

Comment: Yes, I try to mark your answer but it says wait 5 more minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The function is defined on $(0,\infty)$.

Start with: $$x^{\cos x}=e^{\ln x^{\cos x}}=e^{{\cos x}\ln x}$$

Now apply chain rule:$$\cdots=e^{{\cos x}\ln x}\left[-\sin x\ln x+\frac{\cos x}{x}\right]=x^{\cos x}\left[-\sin x\ln x+\frac{\cos x}{x}\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

use $x^{\cos(x)} = e^{\ln(x^{\cos(x)})}= e^{\cos(x)\ln(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $x^{\cos(x)}=e^{\cos(x)\ln(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=x^{\cos(x)}$.  Now take the log of both sides:

$$\log(y) = \cos(x) \log(x). $$

Now differentiate both sides (with the product rule):

$$ \frac{y'}{y} = -\sin(x) \log(x) + \cos(x) \frac{1}{x}.$$

Note that $y'$ (the expression we seek) equals
$$ y' = y\left[ -\sin(x) \log(x) + \cos(x) \frac{1}{x} \right]. $$

Replace the original expression for $y$ into the above and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Usually functions with a variable in the base and exponent are best done by passing to the logarithm:
$$x^{\cos x}= e^{\cos x \log x}$$
Which by the chain rule has derivative 
$$(\cos x \log x)’ e^{\cos x \log x}= (\frac{\cos x}{x} -\sin x \log x) e^{\cos x \log x} $$